# How to place JSON return values to HTML in MVC 4?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller which returns list of values through Json

here is my code.

```
var list = new List<string>();
...

foreach(var key in collection.AllKeys)`
{
    ...
    list.Add(value)`;   
}

return Json(new
    {
        ItemName= ItemName
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Now how do I write return JSON values to Html?
Here I tried in jquery

```
var $Items = $(".Items");

$.post("/Orders/GetItems", ItemId, function (data) {
        $(data).each(function() {
        var $element = $Items.clone().removeClass("Items").appendTo("#data");
        $element.attr("id", this.ItemName);
        $element.html(this.ItemName);
    });
```

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the second ItemName in `return Json(new {ItemName= ItemName })`?

In controller return the whole list:

```
return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and js:

```
$.post("/Orders/GetItems", ItemId, function (data) {
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        var $element = $Items.clone().removeClass("Items").appendTo("#data");
        $element.attr("id", data[i]);//??
        $element.html(data[i]);
    }
});
```

Or may be I didn't understand your intention. You can explain more if it's not correct.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Let me try your solution first otherwise I will try to explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: I got `undefined` in `data.lenth` even though there is some values in `data`. Can you help me out on this one?

Comment: it's `data.length` not `data.lenth`.

Comment: typo - I used `data.length`

Comment: If you sent the whole list,`data` must be an array in js so it have to have length property. what are the values in data (js)?

Comment: I got it, thank you for your help. `for(var i=0;i<data.list.length;i++)`. Now the problem is I can't write values to html.